# Is it safe to do `element.style.setProperty` from a XSS perspective

Tags: css, xss, css-variables

Assuming I do this:

```
element.style.setProperty('--my-var', unescapedUserInput);
```

And `unescapedUserInput` is a unescaped user input, is this a security issue? If yes what would be a possible attack?

Comment: How does the user input get put into that variable? If you simply server-side echo into a script tag like this: `element.style.setProperty('--my-var',<%=unescapedUserInput%>);`, then it is not safe. If it is pulled from elsewhere in the DOM... maybe safe? I personally would need more information to answer.

Comment: Assume it's a string obtained from the user in a safe way. That's the assumption here. The question is if there is any combination of css and a evil css var setted in that way that is unsafe.

Comment: The Scripting part of XSS should not be an issue, because it’s CSS and not JS - so it’s not likely to steal my cookies or something like that. What “damage” it could possibly do otherwise, mostly depends on how you _use_ that variable in the rest of your CSS, I suppose. For example used in the `content` property of a form button it could make that say something different than it originally did, make it "Create super-safe backup” instead of the original button text “Delete forever” (although that again would perhaps be more an issue of user input validation, rather than escaping.)